# Contract constructor parameter which is also a contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, binance-smart-chain, binance-chain

I have contract in solidity MasterChef.sol which can be seen at the link below
https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-farm/tree/master/contracts
I want to deploy it using truffle on the Binance smart chain and the question is that the constructor of the MasterChef.sol takes in 5 args and two of them are contracts I want to know that how to pass the other two contracts i.e CakeToken.sol and SyrupBar.sol as the first two args in the deploy_contracts.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need deploy other contracts beforehand, write down their addresses and pass addresses when MasterChef is deployed.

Comment: How to pass address as an arg in the javascript file?

Comment: is it passed like "0x123123123123123123123123123" like this ? @Mikko Ohtamaa

Comment: Yes. You are correct. You need to pay attention to hex letter capitalisation because it is the source of checksum in Ethereum.

Comment: How to interact with the contract deployed on BSC using truffle? @Mikko Ohtamaa

Comment: That is an another question. I suggest you look up tutorials on this topic.